# Python 3.8.3 (Spyder 4.1.4) Type Error: an integer is required (got type _NoValueType)

Tags: python, typeerror, spyder

I am currently working through the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow" by Aurélien Géron and I get the above error when I execute the following code in Spyder. Jupyter on the other hand does not complain.

```
import os 
import tarfile 
import urllib 

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"

HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")

HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url = HOUSING_URL, housing_path = HOUSING_PATH): 
    os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok = True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz") 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path) 
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path) 
    housing_tgz.extractall(path = housing_path) 
    housing_tgz.close()
    
import pandas as pd 

def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH): 
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv") 
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

fetch_housing_data()
housing = load_housing_data()
print(housing.head())
```

The error:

```
 File "C:\Users\ma\untitled0.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(housing.head())

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 744, in __repr__
    self.to_string(

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 883, in to_string
    return formatter.to_string(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 921, in to_string
    return self.get_result(buf=buf, encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 520, in get_result
    self.write_result(buf=f)

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 834, in write_result
    strcols = self._to_str_columns()

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 770, in _to_str_columns
    fmt_values = self._format_col(i)

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 954, in _format_col
    return format_array(

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1179, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1210, in get_result
    fmt_values = self._format_strings()

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1258, in _format_strings
    & np.all(notna(vals), axis=tuple(range(1, len(vals.shape))))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in all

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2411, in all
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.logical_and, 'all', axis, None, out, keepdims=keepdims)

  File "C:\Users\ma\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type _NoValueType)
```

Could it be related to the fact that one attribute is an object?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: First thing that sticks out: line 34 is actually line 27. And what is this "Python 4.1.4" from the title?

Comment: This could be specific to spyder. The example you provided runs (more or less) without error, so I couldn't reproduce your issue. It could also be that urllib is not downloading the file as you expect, so the pandas operations are working on an empty file

Comment: many thanks. sorry, how can i check whether the file is not empty? thanks again

Comment: @Markus, you need to look for a file called `housing.tgz` in the same directory where you're saved the file you're trying to run.